# Entity Framework Migration API

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Hi i have made a data sync project on top of entity framework.
the framework is schema independent to some extent.
i want to make it more tolerant to changes in schema even the currently considered breaking changes.

to achieve this i will have to get inside the ef migration engine and will have to generate a command like

```
add-transformation
```

which will be detecting the changes and creating a transformation.

I have looked into the source code of ef 6 but couldnt find an appropriate place to start.
any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1 :- answer to questions received in the comments

1. Code First Approach
2. Extent:
   Changes in data will be handled by the migration so no need to incorporate the changes.
   What I need to is a way to execute a command like `add-transformation` which would create a new transformation like a new migration. So typically lets say i have a database model (domain model) like

   class A 
   {
    public int a {get; set;}
    public int b {get; set;}
   }

then i change the class to the structure

```
class A 
{
 public int a {get; set;}
 public int b {get; set;}
 public int c {get; set;}
}
```

and then i run `add-tranformation ClassChangesA` 
the code i require should 
1. Detect changes
2. Generate a class like the migration class. Ex.

```
class Transformation_112334_ClassChangesA
{
 public A Up(OldA model){
   //Property C added
 }
 public OldA Down(A model){
   //Property C removed
 }
}
```

Comment: Assuming your approach to be code first , i would advise you to go through MSDN article
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: First question Code first or DB First approach? Second question, about "extent" what your data sync app should do? a. Ignore the changes (add fields? add tables?) or b. replicate also the data contained in new changes (fields or what?)? Third question, can you recompile your sync app after someone "extent" the database?

Comment: @bubi - i have answered ur question by editing the answer. Kindly see it.

Comment: i am also willing to increase the bounty if someone is willing to answer the question to abt a 100 points

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the command you are looking for is **add-migration migration_name**
then you can update your database using the command **update-database**, this is how to work with code first migrations in entity framework.